# AngularJs Services with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-services, isolate-scope, one-time-binding

In my Angular app i have a service, that stores a Configuration structure, that is used by various components of my app. In the `.run`-phase that `guiConfigService` reads the configurations from a `.json` file by the function `setGuiConfig` and is able to return data for a certain component by the function `getGuiConfig`:

```
myApp.factory("guiConfigService", ['$http', function($http) {
   var guiConfig = {};
   var self = {
        setGuiConfig: function (callback) {
          guiConfig = {"Functions" : {
            "FunctionIds" : [
              "3",
              "5",
              "10",
              "last_entry"
            ]
          }};
          if (undefined !== callback) {
            callback(guiConfig);
          }
        },
        getGuiConfig: function (buzzword, callback) {
            callback(guiConfig[buzzword]);
        }
    }
    return self;
 }]);
```

**My Problem:**

In the controller of my component i want to be able to manipulate whatever i get back from the `getGuiConfig` function of my service, let's say, i want to remove the last entry of the attribute `FunctionIds`. This manipulation does not only affect the object in my cotroller, but also manipulates the `guiConfig`-Object in my Service.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, guiConfigService) {

    var configData;

  $scope.getNewGuiConfig = function() {
    guiConfigService.getGuiConfig('Functions', function(data) {
        configData = data;
         // this does not only affect `configData`, but also the 
         // `guiConfig`-Object in guiConfigService:
         configData.FunctionIds.splice(-1);
    });
  }
}
```

See [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2n2tpkb9/1/) for example.

**What I tried already:**

- First I thought, the problem is me calling a callback-function and not returning the object directly, but I tried and it does not seem to work either.
- Sending a copy of my Service's `guiConfig` Object by `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(guiConfig[buzzword]))` is working but does not seem to me like the right way to do.

Is there a good way to return data from an object in service , without the reference to the actual object?

Comment: You can use angular.copy() in your callback function.

Comment: Usual code for configs in controller is ~:
config = angular.extend(ctrl.config || {}, service.getNewGuiConfig());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the services are singleton in angular.So you can make a copy of config data in your controller and modify it accordingly.
>   According to me you should use constant service to store your app configurations and always make a copy of your configurations when you want to manipulate them using angular.copy().

```
function MyCtrl($scope, guiConfigService) {
   var configData;
   $scope.getNewGuiConfig = function() {
      guiConfigService.getGuiConfig('Functions', function(data) {
       configData = angular.copy(data);
       configData.FunctionIds.splice(-1);
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: As the service is used in multiple components, i'd say it makes more sense to have the service make the copy than the controller. Otherwise, Thank you!